# jQuery load() issue with html that contain jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

FYI, here is my code:

[index.html]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

[script.js]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#buttonEphone').click(function() {
        $('#apDiv2').load("ePhone.html, #content");
    });
});
```

"ePhone.html" contain some lightbox effect. (making use of code below)

[ePhone.html]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.lite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moo.fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/litebox-1.0.js"></script>
```

The Litebox plugin also required to add `onload="initLightbox()"` within the BODY tag of ePhone.html.

From the above code, I can load ePhone.html's content(#content div) to my `<div>`(apDiv2) of my index.html. However, the lightbox effect is no longer work.
I've also try loading the whole html instead of only #content:

```
$('#apDiv2').load('ePhone.html');
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to had those script in your `index.html`?

Comment: actually, I put the code in my script.js. 
within my index.html, I have this line:
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

Comment: Are these three `<script>`-tags _in_ that `#content div`?

Comment: yes, I just tried and it still doesn't work. Btw, this plugin also required to put: "onload="initLightbox()" within the BODY tag.

Comment: @Victorgalaxy: That changes everything. Add the `initLightbox()` call in the callback of the `.load()` function.

Comment: @elusive: Sorry, Could you plz show me how? (I just started learning jQuery yesterday :P) Thx

Comment: @Victorgalaxy: I recommend reading through the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load). They tell you that the callback is always the last parameter: `$('#apDiv2').load('ePhone.html #content', function () { initLightbox(); });`. And I think the `,` in your url-selector is unnecessary.

Comment: @elusive: I tried the code below and it doesn't work neither:

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#buttonEphone').click(function() {
$('#apDiv2').load('ePhone.html #content', function () { 
initLightbox();
 $.getScript('prototype.lite.js', function() {
     $.getScript('moo.fx.js', function() {
      $.getScript('litebox-1.0.js', function() {
  });
  });
  });
});
});

});

I've also try putting the initLightbox(); after those 3 getscript function...also try putting within the last getscript function and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Victorgalaxy: You are mixing two entirely different approaches here. My example did not contain any `getScript`-function.

Comment: @elusive: Ok, I ALMOST got it now.  With your method.(without those getscripts function). It works if I load the whole ePhone.html:
$('#apDiv2').load('ePhone.html').  But it's still not working for $('#apDiv2').load('ePhone.html #content').

Comment: @Victorgalaxy: The script tags are in the `#content` element? I have no other ideas if that is the case...

Answer (score 0):

As `.load()` is a shortcut for `.bind('load', handler)` and there is issues with using existing functionality with new elements loaded into the DOM via `.bind()`, try using the `.live('load', handler)` instead to accomplish your task.

`.live()` offers the same functionality as `.bind()` with the added benefit that any elements within the loaded data will be affected by any scripts you currently use.

**EDIT**

From your comment above on using the `<body onload="">` attribute you should probably know this:

"*The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the  attribute. If load must be used, either do not use .ready() or use jQuery's .load() method to attach load event handlers to the window or to more specific items, like images*."

**EDIT 2**

Try this:

```
$('#apDiv2').live('load', 'ePhone.html, #content', function(){
    //Add extra stuff here if you need to
});
```

Comment: sorry I'm very new to jQuery.  How can I replace ".load()" with ".live()" to my code above? I'll appreciate if you can show me. Thx

Answer (score 0):

In Browser, Javascript executes upon certain event. At page loading, after page is loaded, or any defined events.. so on..

But when you try loading the HTML via ajax in some DIV, and that HTML contains some JS, then browser will not execute that JS, because that JS is not registered in DOM of browser.

So, What you can do is,
Keep only HTML in ePhone.html, And move out all of the JS script from that page, and keep that JS on index.html. And use live() for binding whatever events you registered in ePhone.html.

That will make it working.

Thanks!

Hussain

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getScript` function to dinamically load scripts after `jquery.load` function completed.
try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#buttonEphone').click(function() {
  $('#apDiv2').load("ePhone.html, #content", function(){

   // load complete
   // now dynamically load the script

    $.getScript('js/prototype.lite.js', function() {
     $.getScript('js/moo.fx.js', function() {
      $.getScript('js/litebox-1.0.js', function() {
         // init lightbox here
      });
     });
    });

  });
 });
});
```